# My test cases fail when all test cases are run. But passing when ran individually

Tags: java, selenium

```
//This command is for scrolling into view of an element
public static void scrollIntoView(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
}

//This command will make the script wait until a certain element is visible before doing any actions
public static void untilVisibility(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Helper.TWENTY);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}

//This command will make the script wait until a certain element is clickable before doing any actions
public static void untilClickable(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Helper.TWENTY);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
}
```

I'm using these three methods for my testcases, but sometimes the script is still unable to wait for the visibility of the elements, or even if the element is displayed while running, it still fails. But when I re-run them, they pass individually

For example I have 98 test cases, on the first run 20 will fail, but when I rerun the 20 test cases, they pass

Comment: You could try reloading the page before each test (if you aren't already). You could also try to find a smaller set of tests which has this problem, that might narrow down the cause.

Comment: How is the wait configured? can you share the code?

Answer (score -1):

Could you provide the exception message? I guess the Exception is caused by these test methods using the same object that does not support using simultaneously, like IO of files.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean about Exception message? Is it like the error message? The error returned is that the script is unable to locate the element via xpath declared in my page. But if I run it independently it's failing

Comment: Yes, it is the error message. Whether these methods' execution with an order in a thread pool, such as Executors? Why do they have errors sometimes? Opposite, they are correct. Could you consider the execution orders?